# Mac OS X admin password reset utility

Tags: macos, mac, security

Is there any way i can reset my mac admin password with a tool like chntpw. Booting from a Mac OS X Install CD is not an option, since the firmware password is set. Are there any simple ways of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following guide from osxdaily if you choose:

http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/19/bypass-mac-firmware-password/

There are a few ways around even a firmware password, but they take time.

Comment: A short summary of the instructions could be useful. The webpage might dissapear.

Comment: Hi, i don't actually own a Mac, i have a cloned hard disk image. I just want to know if i can reset the admin password without booting it, like you can in Windows if you have read/write access to the HD

Comment: I will put up the full on directions and include some other ways shortly.